# Where is God according to Christianity?

Tags: nature-of-god

Sometimes to make the idea controversial, atheists depict God as a humanly being residing in the space and then compare him to other fairy tale creatures. To counter this, some sort of logical or may be philosophical answer is needed to the question, "**Where** is God?"
What is an overview of the positions within Christianity about this subject?

Answer (score 9):

While this isn't true for ***all*** branches of Christianity, the vast majority of Christianity believes God to be Omnipresent - that is, everywhere at once.

From http://www.parentcompany.com/awareness_of_god/aog11.htm

> **God is Omnipresent**
>
> The attribute of God by which He fills the universe in all its parts
>   and is present everywhere at once. Not a part, but the whole of God is
>   present in every place. This is true of all three members of the
>   Trinity. They are so closely related that where one is the others can
>   be said to be, also.

That page lists several verses from Scripture that support this attribute of God.

See also

- http://www.theopedia.com/Omnipresence_of_God
- http://www.unionchurch.com/archive/050700.html
- http://www.apologeticspress.org/APContent.aspx?category=11&article=2690
- http://www.enjoyinggodministries.com/article/the-omnipresence-of-god/

This *generally* goes along with the idea that God is Spirit (John 4:24), and not a physical being of flesh and bone.  Although some denominations, like the [LDS, teach that God is a being of flesh and bone](http://mormon.org/faq/nature-of-god), and that omnipresence has a slightly different meaning.

For many Christians, God is also not limited to our universe. As the self-existing Creator ***of*** the universe, He us greater than it, and not limited ***to*** the universe.

http://www.everystudent.com/wires/finger.html

Comment: +1 for "Creator of the universe ... not limited to the universe."

Comment: is space bigger than universe? Does God need space to fit in?

Comment: @owari - I assume you're addressing the "For many Christians, God is not limited to our universe" portion.  Note that I didn't say "All Christians".  But those Christians that do hold that view (like me) God does not need to fit into space.  Space was created by God. God existed before space, and before time.  He created space and time.  So the answer to the second part of your question, to those that believe this way, is "no, God doesn't need space to fit in."  External support for this doctrinal position: http://christian-oneness.org/about-God/chapter1.html

Comment: thanks for the clarification, but my problem still persists. According to the link you cited in your comment "He exists both outside His creation and at every point within it" but "outside the universe" has no meaning unless there is a background space out there. Am I missing a point?

Comment: Yes, but not an obvious one.  The point is that God transcends creation, but in our finite understanding, we really don't know what that means, other than that He is greater then the universe.  But that shouldn't be too hard to believe.  Even atheistic physicists believe thare could be multiple universes - an infinite amount, so what we know as "the universe", space, and time, could be only part of the picture. The more we learn about our universe, the m,ore we realize we don't understand.  All we know is that His word (Old Testament as well as new) teaches that He is self-existing and eternal

Comment: Actually, the first link gives an illustration that I personally find useful.  http://www.parentcompany.com/awareness_of_god/aog11.htm  I think of it as an allegory - our known universe would be the "flat world" that God exists outside  of.  Other explanations that use the flat world analogy postulate that there are more dimensions than we can detect, and that God fills those.  (Again, there are theories in physics that also fit - some predicting many different dimensions instead of the 4 we know (height, depth, width, and time.) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superstring_theory#Extra_dimensions

Comment: yes, I am aware of all those "other universes" and "extra dimensions" but I don't think you would assume God to exists in all those universes and dimensions but not then also outside them, and the problem is with this "outside" thing. This will limit God to some space thing which would contradict His perfectness, not being limited I mean. Maybe even if we extend the extensions of space containing all such universes and the number of dimensions to infinity still the limitation of requiring a space to be present in be an imperfection!?

Comment: However, thanks for your time, maybe I should continue thinking.

Answer (score 1):

A number of positions may exist within Christianity, but are they not regarded as contradictory. Most Christians today generally believe that God is [omnipresent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipresence), throughout the entire universe and beyond.

Daniel 2:28 reflects an earlier belief, telling us specifically that God is in heaven:

> [Daniel 2:28](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Daniel&chapter=2&verse=28): But there is a **God in heaven** that revealeth secrets, and maketh known to the king Nebuchadnezzar what shall be in the latter days. Thy dream, and the visions of thy head upon thy bed, are these;

Somewhat like *Daniel*, Acts of the Apostles tells us that God is up in heaven above, seated next to Jesus; a view that has never entirely gone away and is sometimes mentioned to this day:

> [Acts 7:55](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Acts&chapter=7&verse=55): But he, being full of the Holy Ghost, looked up stedfastly into **heaven, and saw the glory of God**, and Jesus standing on the right hand of God,

We then go to the Church Fathers such as Augustine and Thomas Aquinas. John M. Perry says in *[Exploring the Evolving View of God](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Oe55TvGC2ZIC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=augustine%20god%20present%20aquinas&source=bl&ots=rg0JIFedzM&sig=jbzCGLCFR7t2Yuy9oS53rmtpW-c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBWoVChMI9bry_JCCxwIVBCmmCh03cwDv#v=onepage&q=augustine%20god%20present%20aquinas&f=false)*, page 167, that Augustine taught that God is present in all creatures yet transcends them, but Aquinas said that God is not, and can not be, intimately related to the world.

Answer (score 0):

In the Bible, God the Father is commonly seen in visions as seated on a throne in heaven. This is not necessarily contradictory to the idea that God is omnipresent, since He can be omnipresent and also still take on a form.

Daniel 7 9-14 (KJV)

> I beheld till the thrones were cast down, and **the Ancient of days did sit, whose garment was white as snow, and the hair of his head like the pure wool: his throne was like the fiery flame**, and his wheels as burning fire.  A fiery stream issued and came forth from before him: thousand thousands ministered unto him, and ten thousand times ten thousand stood before him: the judgment was set, and the books were opened... I saw in the night visions, **and, behold, one like the Son of man came with the clouds of heaven, and came to the Ancient of days**, and they brought him near before him. And there was given him dominion, and glory, and a kingdom... (Daniel 7 9-14 KJV)

Revelation 3:21

> To him that overcometh will I grant to sit with me in **my throne**, even as I also overcame, and am set down **with my Father in his throne**.**

Revelation 4:2 - 5:6

> And immediately I was in the spirit: and, behold, a throne was set in
>   heaven, **and one sat on the throne. And he that sat was to look upon
>   like a jasper and a sardine stone**: and there was a rainbow round about
>   the throne, in sight like unto an emerald... and I beheld, and, lo, in the midst of the throne and of the four beasts, and in the midst of the elders, **stood a Lamb** as it had been slain, having seven horns and seven eyes, which are the seven Spirits of God sent forth into all the earth.

Isaiah 6:1-3

> In the year that king Uzziah died I saw also **the Lord sitting upon a
>   throne, high and lifted up, and his train filled the temple**. Above
>   it stood the seraphims: each one had six wings; with twain he covered
>   his face, and with twain he covered his feet, and with twain he did
>   fly. And one cried unto another, and said, Holy, holy, holy, is the
>   Lord of hosts: **the whole earth is full of his glory**.

Obviously, these visions do not depict a God that is of fairy tale quality just because His sits on a throne. They depict a God of unimaginable surpassing glory that even angels shield their faces with their wings.